# Finding basis given dual basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, $V'$ is its dual space, and $\{\phi_1, \dots, \phi_n\}$ is a basis for $V'$. Suppose I have found $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ with $v_i \in V$ and that $\phi_i(v_j) = \delta_{ij}$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq n$. Is $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ necessarily a basis for $V$?

(Note: I think YES because the double dual basis exists and is unique, and then $V''$ is canonically isomorphic to $V$. But, I want to be sure. Thanks in advance!)

Comment: I think you are correct. The Basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is the (unique) dual basis of $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\}$.

Comment: Yes: Assume $\sum_{j} a^jv_j = 0$ for some scalars $a^j$; apply the $\phi_j$ to both sides, concluding that $a^j=0$ for all $j$.

Comment: Revising the last comment slightly: Apply $\phi_k$. The index $j$ is being summed.